# Graph of everywhere continuous non-differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

W. Rudin gives the following example $f(x)$.

Let $\varphi(x) = |x|$ on $[-1,1]$ and extend periodically to the whole real line with period $2$.

Now define

$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n\varphi(4^nx).$$

How does the graph of this function, or its successive approximations, look like? Just to get an idea of how continuity happens, but not differentiability.

Comment: I suspect that $\varphi$ is defined on $[-1,1]$, and that the function is supposed to be $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac34\right)^n\varphi(4^nx)\;.$$

Answer (score 11):

The image to keep in mind is to start with the V, and at each step of the approximaton you add a set of $\frac{3}{4}$-of-the-previous-size smaller V's. The $\frac{3}{4}$ is just to give convergence, and the $4^n$ is to give more and more V's close to every real number.

But this would lead you to believe that the shape is very jagged, sort of like the classic Weierstrass no-where differentiable function: [image: Weierstrass]

But that's not really true. In fact, the successive additions almost 'smooth' out the 'jags' of most of the sides of the V's. On [this blog page](http://divisbyzero.com/2009/12/02/an-applet-illustrating-a-continuous-nowhere-differentiable-function/) (not my blog, but instead divisbyzero), there is a picture of an essentially-the-same function:

[image]

This is actually the function $\displaystyle \sum \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n \varphi (2^n x)$, but I think that might see the similarity. On your function, the function would get a bit larger ($3/4 > 1/2$) and so the crests and troughs would be a bit deeper, etc.

One good bit about the $1/2$ function is that the blogger of DivisionByZero (the blog I linked to above) also wrote up an [applet](http://users.dickinson.edu/~richesod/math361/nowherediff.html) illustrating the successive approximations of the function.

Comment: I don't understand "that's not really true" part. There is an essential difference between $3/4$ (or anything larger than $1/2$) and the critical value $1/2$. The first graph has Hausdorff dimension greater than 1 (though precise value is unknown, I think), the second has Hausdorff dimension 1, same as any smooth curve.

Answer (score 1):

mixedmath has already explained most of the mathematics in his answer. Here, I'll just provide *Mathematica* code that people can play around with:

```
φ[x_] := TriangleWave[{0, 1}, -x/2 - 1/4];
rudin[x_, n_Integer] := Sum[(3/4)^k φ[x 4^k], {k, 0, n}];

Animate[Plot[rudin[x, n], {x, 0, 2}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True, 
  MaxRecursion -> 4, PlotLabel -> StringForm["n=`1`", n], 
  PlotPoints -> 105, PlotRange -> {0, 7/2}], {n, 1, 6}]
```

[image: Rudin's example]

I decided not to include the plots for $n > 6$; at that point, the function already looks sufficiently messy to be indistinguishable from the $n=6$ partial sum.

Comment: And here's the blancmange curve: [interactive applet by Dave Richeson](http://users.dickinson.edu/~richesod/math361/nowherediff.html).